# I can't middle click sites to open them in background tabs

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, user-experience

https://stackexchange.com/sites

Also the names for all the different exchanges are cute but non-intuitive.
edit: I see the less-commonly known exchanges have been given simpler names. This was a good decision.

Comment: It works for me (Chrome 20). They're just normal links, so I don't know what the issue would be

Comment: No repro, can you be more specific about what you're doing?  I visit http://stackexchange.com/sites, I click on a site to expand its listing, and then clicking on the 'Visit Site' button/link works as I'd expect it to background opening or not.

Comment: if I click one of the blobs first, and then middle click, it will open them in the background. I'd like to just middle click the blob and go...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to list view by clicking on the button in the upper right:

[image]

Then you can middle-click to open sites to your heart's content.

Answer (score 2):

That's because those little dialogue-bubbles aren't hyperlinks... you must click to expand them. Once the bubble expands you'll see a "visit site" link which functions as expected in IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome 21, and Firefox 15.

Comment: yes, but why can't I just click and go? Why would I want to expand them, let alone be required to?